# mongoDB mongoose unique index vs unique

Tags: mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a schema like this :

```
var UserSchema = new Schema({
    username : {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        unique : true,
        index: { unique: true },
        trim: true
    },
    password : {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
})
```

on saving to db this gives me doc like this :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5b43827de210a92130b99ccf"
    },
    "username": "username1",
    "password": "password1",
    "__v": 0
}
```

The id changes for every doc.In this case even if i remove 
`index: { unique: true }`
So is this necessary?or is just `unique : true` on username enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can write two ways both are equivalent so you don't need to write both

```
name: { type: String, unique: true }
```

or

```
name: { type: String, index: { unique: true } }
```